# Can we change app icon at runtime in uwp?

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to change the app icon at runtime, for example, I need to show an exclamation mark if there is no network connectivity

Comment: You can use a [badge notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/badges).

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond Chen said, you can use [badge notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/badges) when there is no network connection. The "attention" glyph badge displays as an exclamation mark, you can use it as a badge. For example:

```
private void updateBadgeGlyph()
{
    string badgeGlyphValue = "attention";

    // Get the blank badge XML payload for a badge glyph
    XmlDocument badgeXml = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeGlyph);

    // Set the value of the badge in the XML to our glyph value
    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement badgeElement = badgeXml.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement;
    badgeElement.SetAttribute("value", badgeGlyphValue);

    // Create the badge notification
    BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeXml);

    // Create the badge updater for the application
    BadgeUpdater badgeUpdater = BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();

    // And update the badge
    badgeUpdater.Update(badge);
}
```

**Update:**

> > if there is no network connectivity

There is a [NetworkHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/networkhelper) class to monitor the changes in network connection, you can subscribe the NetworkChanged event and judge the IsInternetAvailable. When the network is not available, show the badge.

```
NetworkHelper.Instance.NetworkChanged += Instance_NetworkChanged;

private async void Instance_NetworkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NetworkHelper.Instance.ConnectionInformation.IsInternetAvailable)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //clear badge
        });
    }
   else
   {
       await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
       {
           updateBadgeGlyph();
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can the following method help? Have you solved your issue?

Comment: No, I cant show using BadgeNotification. I can change the icon in system trey but dont know how to do it for app icon (taskbar icon)

Comment: When you detect that the network is not connected, you could directly the updateBadgeGlyph() method, then the icon will add the badge. Do you mean when you call the above method, it cannot work?

Comment: I am already using badge notification to show unread message count if application is in background, so its quite difficult to maintain both

Comment: I need some other solution to change the app icon